# MySql auto_increment plus a certain number

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I want my the id field in my table to be a bit more " random" then consecutive numbers.

Is there a way to insert something into the id field, like a +9, which will tell the db to take the current auto_increment value and add 9 to it?

Comment: So how adding a 9 to each id will make it "random"?

Comment: 9 is just a placeholder, the randomness will be dealt with in php. @jackwilliams, what would that insert statement look like?

Comment: Sorry, I only skimmed through the question.

Comment: Do you want your program to do it for you or mysql ? You can create a trigger that will update the auto-increment value before the insertion.

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan I'd prefer to do it in mysql, and I want to limit my database calls.

Comment: @General_Twyckenham Since `AUTO_INCREMENT` is an int value, are you trying to do an addition or a concatenation ?

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan Addition is fine.  I really just want to increment by `small_random_number` more than 1 instead of incrementing by 1

Comment: `small_random_number` ? You need to define how small. In my solution just remplace `+9;` by `+RAND(x);` , where x is the range of your 'random' number. It should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a design flaw. Leave the auto increment alone and shuffle your query result (when you fetch your data)

Answer (score 1):

Though this is generally used to solve replication issues, you can set an increment value for auto_increment:

[auto_increment_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment)

Since that is both a session and a global setting, you could simply set the session variable just prior to the insert.

Besides that, you can manually do it by getting the current value with `MAX()` then add any number you want and insert that value. MySQL will let you know if you try to insert a duplicate value.

Comment: This answer is technically correct. Debate in comments, not with down votes.

Comment: I am the downvoter and let me explain why : this guy wants to shuffle (or randomize) data. You are pushing some tech solutions when the design is actually very bad. If he needs to shuffle records, then it should happen on the fetching and not the storing. Messing with auto increment is probably the worst solution and idea there is and it just goes against database design.

Comment: @Eric I don't actually want to randomize data. It should be mostly consistent, I (or rather, my partner) just don't want for the id's to be too consecutive.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind this ?

Comment: It's rather frivolous, but it's so that order ID's don't appear too linear.

Comment: I don't get it either and no-one's justified it, yet.

Comment: @JackWilliams While this isn't the most palatable use-case, one benefit is that repeat customers don't have consecutive orderID's, leading them to wonder about the legitimacy of the product.

Comment: Providing that orderID's are not duplicates, that's irrelevant.

Comment: Makes sense to me. You can very easily give away internal business statistics via your order numbers. Better to have them non-linear. Let's not be too closed minded eh folks?

Answer (score 0):

### As far as i know, it's not possible to 'shuffle' your current IDs. If you wanted though, you could pursue non-linear IDs in the future.

***The following is written in PDO, there are [mysqli equivalents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php).***

**This is just an arbitrary `INSERT` statement**

```
$name = "Jack";
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
$sql = "INSERT INTO tableName (name) VALUES(:name)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(':name' => $name);
```

**Next, we use `lastInsertId()` to return the ID of the last inserted row, then we concatenate the result to `rand()`**

```
$lastID = $conn->lastInsertId();
$randomizer = $lastID.rand();
```

**Finally, we use our 'shuffled' ID  and `UPDATE` the previously inserted record.**

```
$sql = "UPDATE tableName SET ID = :randomizer WHERE ID=:lastID ";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':lastID' => $lastID , ':randomizer' => $randomizer));
```

Answer (score 0):

An idea.. (Not tested)

1. `CREATE TRIGGER` 'updateMyAutoIncrement'
2. `BEFORE INSERT`
3. `ON` 'DatabaseName'.'TableName'
4. `FOR EACH ROW`
5. `BEGIN`
6. `DECLARE` aTmpValueHolder `INT DEFAULT 0;`
7. `SELECT` `AUTO_INCREMENT INTO` aTmpValueHolder
8. `FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`
9. `WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA =` 'DatabaseName'
10. `AND   TABLE_NAME =` 'TableName'`;`
11. `SET NEW`.idColumnName `=`aTmpValueHolder `+ 9;`
12. `END`;

Edit : If the above trigger doesn't work try to update `AUTO_INCREMENT` value directly into the system's schema. But as noted by Eric, your design seems to be flawed. I don't see the point of having an auto-increment here.

Edit 2 : For a more 'random' and less linear number.

1. `SET NEW`.idColumnName `=`aTmpValueHolder `+ RAND(10);`

Edit 3 : As pointed out by Jack Williams, `Rand()` produces a `float` value between 0 and 1.
So instead, to produce an integer, we need to use a floor function to transform the 'random' float into an integer.

`SET NEW`.idColumnName `=`aTmpValueHolder `+  FLOOR(a + RAND() * (b - a));`

where a and b are the range of the random number.

Comment: `+ 9` was a placeholder, OP want's a random number.

Comment: OP can then replace `+9;` by `+RAND(x);` where x is the greatest possible random number.

Comment: Sure, not in MySQL though.

Comment: What not ? Please explain.

Comment: Well, you could, but it would only be between 0 and 1.

Comment: You are right on this. Then you can use a floor function to convert it into an integer.